# puppet resource command with title munge

Tags: resources, puppet, title, case-insensitive

I've created a puppet resource for interfaces. Most of the interface names on my switch are lowercase with the exception of Ethernet interfaces, so I munged the interface name to hopefully reduce errors in the manifest; e.g.:

manifest:

```
  cisco_interface { 'Ethernet1/1': description => 'foo' }
```

type/cisco_interface.rb:

```
  newparam(:name) do
    munge { |value|
      value.downcase
    }  
  end
```

My provider code also downcases the interface names when I collect the list of interfaces with self.instances.

Okay, so this works great when I test with the manifest, but not so great with the puppet resource command which only works when I call it with the name already downcased:

```
switch# puppet resource cisco_interface 'Ethernet1/1'
cisco_interface { 'Ethernet1/1':
  ensure => 'absent',
}

switch# puppet resource cisco_interface 'ethernet1/1'
cisco_interface { 'ethernet1/1':
  ensure                       => 'present',
  description                  => 'foo',
}
```

The puppet resource command name field seems to just be a simple filter so I think I'm stuck, but I thought I'd seen other resource types munging title values like this.

Is it possible to munge the title values in a way that works for both scenarios?
If not then I'm not sure whether it would be better to leave it case-sensitive since that is what users will see in the switch config, or to "help" them avoid errors in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about what is happening here, puppet currently requires that the name passed into the command line exactly matches the name according to the type. It's buried a couple levels deep, but look at the `find` and `resource_name` methods of the [RAL](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/indirector/resource/ral.rb).

It doesn't seem to me like this would be a major change, so you might want to log a defect or make the change yourself!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll dig through the RAL and submit a fix/defect.